# Starting a long running Scoped Service from a Hosted Service

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm somewhat new to .NET 6 and async programming and have a use case that I haven't been able to grasp yet. I need a Manager type service to start up when the application starts and stops when the application stops. I found AddHostedService using BackgroundService. It runs a loop in ExecuteAsync and works well. I also need Client type services that are started and stopped by the Manager service. They are long running but not necessarily for the life of the application. All Client services are the same class, just having different instance data. So I found Scoped Services. All the examples seem to have the Hosted Service call the Scoped Service every time within the loop. The Scoped Service just does something and returns. First of all, I don't want the Client(s) to start up when the Manager starts, nor do I want them to be started and expected to finish every time the loop runs. So I tied to do something like the following in an ASP.NET application. Keeping in mind that this was just a prototype to see if it would work and the Client is not really meant to be started up once only when the Manager starts.

Manager

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var client = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClient>();
        await client.DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Client

```
public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

This does not block the application. The website starts up. But the goal of having 2 workers running at the same time was not accomplished. What actually happens is the Manager waits until the Client ends and the Client doesn't end until the token is canceled. So the while loop in the Manager never runs. I was actually expecting or hoping that the Manager would keep doing its work while the Client was also doing its work. The pattern seemed ideal. Perhaps I'm just going about this all wrong? If I was still using Framework I'd just create a new instance of Client and have it use a timer to do it's work. Any suggestion about how to start the Client without blocking the Manager would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can keep a data structure with references to client services and clean them up on finish. Then you are not bound to the iteration boundary.

Comment: And if you want things to execute concurrently, it is not enough to make them async. You actually need to `Task.Run` them.

Comment: How long is "long running" btw? I figure it's less than app lifetime but longer than one manager iteration. But is it closer to the former or the latter? You probably also want to consider error handling in your design...

Comment: "long running" could be up to the lifetime of the application but not necessarily. And there may be many running concurrently, within reason of course..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manager code is blocked by waiting client to do the work (`await client.DoWork(stoppingToken);`). To avoid that, you can start new client task without waiting for its completion:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () => {
        using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
        var client = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClient>();
        await client.DoWork(stoppingToken);
    });
}
```

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. I'll give the Task.Run a try. Is that how the application itself starts up the singleton hosted service? What made it confusing for me is that the documentation says that hosted services are started up serially and will not proceed to the next until it becomes async, which the Task.Delay accomplishes. If that's all it takes to let the application proceed, why not for the Manager? Also, the Manager will need to keep a reference to the Clients, like in a Dictionary so that it can send them messages.

Comment: That's related to how async works. An "async" method will execute synchronously _until_ an `await` is encountered. From there, "it depends" but that's from where the Task will be returned, which can (but doesn't need to) be awaited.